# Sql error caused by sequlize bulkCreate. But why?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

This sql query is created by bulkCreate from squelize. But what is wrong about it? And why does it appear?

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
    errno: 1064,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
    sql: "INSERT INTO `account` (`updatedAt`) VALUES ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;",
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: "INSERT INTO `account` (`updatedAt`) VALUES ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),('2021-05-18 11:00:28') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;",
  parameters: undefined
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text... Copy and paste it, and format properly.

Comment: @jarlh sorry, done :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql 8 / maria db

Comment: Don't you have to specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use empty `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Use any fake assigning in it - for example, `id=id`, where `id` is PK of the table. Or `updatedAt = updatedAt`.

But it is more simple to use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `account` (`updatedAt`) 
VALUES ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),
       ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),
       ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),
       ('2021-05-18 11:00:28'),
       ('2021-05-18 11:00:28');
```

`INSERT IGNORE` produces a warning instead of error if unique constrain violated, and the rest of rows is inserted.

In this case `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` not needed at all.

PS. What is the reason to insert 5 equal values into the column which is defined as UNIQUE?